# How to convert decimal to string value for dollars and cents separated in C#?

Tags: c#, decimal, tostring, currency

I need to display decimal money value as string, where dollars and cents are separate with text in between.

```
123.45 => "123 Lt 45 ct"
```

I came up with the following solution:

```
(value*100).ToString("#0 Lt 00 ct");
```

However, this solution has two drawbacks:

1. Upon showing this solution to a fellow programmer, it appears to be unintuitive and requires some explaining.
2. Cents are allways displayed as two digits. (Not real problem for me, as currently this is how I need it to be displayed.)

*Is there any alternative elegant and simple solution?*

Comment: I'm using your solution, I don't see any problem with it - it's elegant and the simplest, works great also. Not sure why it would require explanation. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some errors with accepted answer above (it would drop my result one penny)

Here is my correction

```
 double val = 125.79;
 double roundedVal = Math.Round(val, 2);
 double dollars = Math.Floor(roundedVal);
 double cents = Math.Round((roundedVal - dollars), 2) * 100;
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a fairly simple operation. It should be done in a way, that your fellow programmers understand instantly. Your solution is quite clever, but cleverness is not needed here. =)

Use something verbose like

```
double value = 123.45;
int dollars = (int)value;
int cents = (int)((value - dollars) * 100);
String result = String.Format("{0:#0} Lt {1:00} ct", dollars, cents);
```

Comment: Indeed, a String.Format will do just fine here, and it's easy to read and understand.

Comment: I would do like Jens and then add this as an extensionmethod for Decimal. So you have decimalValue.ToDollarAndCentString(); or similar...

Comment: My first go at it was just like Jens', then I thought of more "elegant" solution (that I posted in my question), but I just hoped there could be some other way. Looks I have to stick with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit over the top:

```
decimal value = 123.45M;

int precision = (Decimal.GetBits(value)[3] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
decimal integral = Math.Truncate(value);
decimal fraction = Math.Truncate((decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision) * (value - integral));

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Lt {1} ct", integral, fraction));
```

The format of the decimal binary representation is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx).